# Get git cache error when merging with custom merge driver

Tags: git, git-merge

Just as a proof of concept I wrote a simple git merge driver in python which merges json files.

Registered in the gitconfig

```
[merge "json-merger"]
  name = poc merge driver
  driver = /lhome/me/workspace/git-driver/merge-driver.py %A %O %B %P
```

add configured in `.gitattributes` with

```
*.json merge=json-merger
```

we get the error message when merging:

> Auto-merging test.json
> error: add_cacheinfo failed to refresh for path 'test.json'; merge aborting

The resulting file's content looks as expected but the merge fails.

Does someone know what could go wrong here?

Comment: Show a bit of your code from your POC merger. If your merge driver did not overwrite the file whose name is supplied by the `%A` option, or exited nonzero, you'd get this. The code where Git produces this error message is a bit dense and I'm not sure if perhaps it might think the file is unchanged if the result of the merge exactly matches the original `%A` file *and* the driver finishes within the stat time resolution of your OS, so if the Python code looks good, perhaps adding a `time.sleep(1)` if the output is exactly the input, would help.

Comment: @torek Your first idea was correct. I debugged git and the found my mistake: The POC merger wrote to the file in the working tree `%P` and not to the temporary file `%A` which was supposed to. Thank you!